# Calling the Methods of another activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, slidingdrawer

Here is my situation. I need to call methods in `activity 2` by being inside `activity 1`. Please have a look at the code of my `activity 1`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/sales_inqury"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/add_new_sales_inqury_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/add_2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="8"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="Search" >
</EditText>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/alphabet_order"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/search_2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/open_alphabet" /> 


    <include layout = "@layout/activity_drop_down_menu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Can you see there is a `include` ?  This where I have added the `activity 2` GUI. `activity 2` is a kind of a menu, where you can slide up and down. Following is `activity 2`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Drag the control at the bottom"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    tools:context=".SlidingDrawerActivity" />

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/slideButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="^" >
    </Button>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="Button 1" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="Button 2" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="Button 3" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Following is the Java code of this activity

```
public class DropDownMenu extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout menuHolder;
    private ImageView menuOpener;

    private Button testButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drop_down_menu);

        testButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        testButton.setOnClickListener(new TestButtonAction());




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drop_down_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //Test Button
    private class TestButtonAction implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(DropDownMenu.this, "WORKING!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(DropDownMenu.this,Home.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }

}
```

Unfortunately this is not working. I guess that's because I didn't start this activity in `activity 1` using `startActivity(Intent)`.

There is no way I can code the `activity 2` in each and every activity, because if I do so, then I have to do it for at least 30 times. So, there should be only 1 "menu code" accessible within other activities.

How can I do this?

Comment: Create a BaseActivity with common menu code and extend your other activities with your base activity

Comment: Seems that fragments are perfectly suitable for the situation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @SankarV: Will that work in android? Because I have used <include> ?

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : create a base class

step 2 : keep the method inside the base class

step 3 : create instance in first activity and access the method in your first activity

step 4 : pass the same base class instance to second activity

step 5 : access the same instance ,thus same method in second activity

Comment: I also thought about this. Will that work in android? Because I have used <include> ? I am sure this works in other languages but here, the <include> seems like a container from anotehr location, that is why

Comment: it will work if you take care of it , dont keep any activity dependant entry in base class , just use it as a bean to pass state of the activity

Answer (score 0):

or you can have a simple java class containing that method.. while instantiating this class you can pass all the parameters that'll be necessary for the method to the constructor like `Context` and all.. then call this method from whichever activity you like..

```
public class Example {

    Context context;

    public Example(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void methodToBeCalled30Times() {
         //do necessary things here using context
    }
}
```